# Create group route with Closure in PHP

Tags: php, routes, closures

How can I create group routing in PHP with Closure? I'm creating my own REST API from scratch in PHP for practice and learning.

In bootstrap file i call **App** class:

```
$app = new App/App();
$app->import('routes.php');
```

I have routes.php file with:

```
$app->group('/api/v1', function() use ($app)
{
    $app->group('/users', function() use ($app)
    {
        $app->get('/', 'User', 'index');
        $app->post('/', 'User', 'post');
        $app->get('/{id}', 'User', 'get');
        $app->put('/{id}', 'User', 'put');
        $app->delete('/{id}', 'User', 'delete');
    });
});
```

It needs to create routes like this:

- /api/v1/users/
- /api/v1/users/
- /api/v1/users/{id}
- /api/v1/users/{id}
- /api/v1/users/{id}

App class:

```
class App
{
    public function group($link, Closure $closure)
    {
        $closure();
    }
}
```

And it sets routes like this:

- /
- /
- /{id}
- /{id}
- /{id}

What should I do to prefix urls ? How can I "foreach" these other $app->get(), $app->post() method callings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Added DI container to App class which handles Router, Route and RouteGroup classes. PHP SLIM framework was my inspiration - https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/tree/3.x/Slim

First I call group() method from App class with calls pushGroup() method from Router class. Then I invoke RouteGroup class with $group();. After that I cal popGroup() to return only last route group.

When adding groups url to Route, just run processGroups() method in Router class to add prefix links.

**App** class

```
/**
 * Route groups
 * 
 * @param string $link
 * @param Closure $closure
 * @return void
 */
public function group($link, Closure $closure)
{
    $group = $this->container->get('Router')->pushGroup($link, $closure);
    $group();
    $this->container->get('Router')->popGroup();
}
```

**Router** class

```
/**
 * Process route groups
 * 
 * @return string
 */
private function processGroups()
{
    $link = '';
    foreach ($this->route_groups as $group) {
        $link .= $group->getUrl();
    }
    return $link;
}


/**
 * Add a route group to the array
 * @param string $link
 * @param Closure $closure
 * @return RouteGroup
 */
public function pushGroup($link, Closure $closure)
{
    $group = new RouteGroup($link, $closure);
    array_push($this->route_groups, $group);
    return $group;
}


/**
 * Removes the last route group from the array
 *
 * @return RouteGroup|bool The RouteGroup if successful, else False
 */
public function popGroup()
{
    $group = array_pop($this->route_groups);
    return ($group instanceof RouteGroup ? $group : false);
}
```

Route class is basic class with routing parameters - method, url, controller, action and additional parameters so I won't copy it here.

**RouteGroup** class

```
/**
 * Create a new RouteGroup
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param Closure $closure
 */
public function __construct($url, $closure)
{
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->closure = $closure;
}

/**
 * Invoke the group to register any Routable objects within it.
 *
 * @param Slinky $app The App to bind the callable to.
 */
public function __invoke()
{
    $closure = $this->closure;
    $closure();
}
```